# Potential Energie equals Mass in GR. Does that mean we can choose mass abitrarily?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, energy, mass

In GR, mass is equal to energy (and appearently, that means also potential Energy). But I can choose an abitrary value for the electromagnetic potential at a certain spot, because for potentials, it's only the derivatives that are interesting. This seems to be a contradiction to me, because the masses of objects can't be abitrarily choosen in the same manner. 
What mistake do I make when thinking it like that?

Answer (score 1):

Mass isn't equal to energy in relativity. The equation that links energy and mass is:

$$ E^2 = p^2c^2 + m^2c^4 $$

where $p$ is the relativistic momentum and $m$ is the rest mass. For a stationary particle the momentum is zero and we recover the expression you are thinking of:

$$ E = mc^2 $$

Energy is a somewhat complicated concept in general relativity. It can only be usefully defined if the spacetime geometry is time independent, in which case we get a **total** energy that is a constant of the motion. There isn't a simple way to split this into a kinetic and potential energy.

The point of all this is that we don't define the energy as the sum of a kinetic and potential energy, so we can't add arbitrary constants to the potential energy and expect this to affect the physics.

Answer (score 0):

The relation between mass and energy is a bit more subtle in GR, and already in special relativity.

But the main point here is relatively simple: In GR, it is the overall energy that determines the spacetime curvature, i.e. the analogue of the gravitational field. To viz, the Einstein equation says
$$ R_{\,u\nu}-\frac{1}{2}Rg_{\mu\nu}= 8\pi G T_{\mu\nu}\,.$$
Here, the lhs contains the spactime geometry, while the right side contains all the non-geometric stuff such as massive particles and light in the so-called energhy-momentum tensor. (I have also lumped the consmological constant into $T_{\mu\nu}$.)

Now you can alerady see the basic difference to the potential enegry in usual mechanics:

- You can add an overall constant to the potential energy (that's what you mean by `choose an abitrary value for the electromagnetic potential at a certain spot`) without changing anything, because the overall value of the energy is irrelevant clasically. (The gravitational field is sourced by masses, not by energy.)
- In GR, any overall constant you add to the "potential energy" ends up in $T_{\mu\nu}$ and thus affects the physics.

Hence, you cannot freely choose the "potential energy" at a given point.

Comment: Does this mean, my potential fixed by some condition? what condition would that be? Something like that we want it to vannish at points that are infinitely far away?

Comment: @Quantumwhisp The potential is what it is and needs to be fixed by some measurement - you cannot impose a "gauge condition", because there is no free overall constant.

Comment: If there isn't a free overall constant, then that means that of all possible electromagnetic potentials, there is only one that doesn't lead to conflicts with general relativity (is that correct?). I'd like to know which of those potentials is the one that doesn't lead to conflicts, and what conditions it has to satisfy.